# Easy way to change Column ID (primary key) of a table to Auto increment

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I started to use SQL Server recently and I still don't know the best way to do some things.

I created all the tables with a column ID as the primary key. Now when I try to insert values I get the following error:

> "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'id', table 'Project.dbo.Table'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. The statement has been terminated."

What is a good, simple solution to this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your table is empty, you can drop and recreate the table again and add `IDENTITY(1,1)` to the column definition of `id` to make your `id` column in `Project.dbo.Table` auto increment.

Something like this.

```
CREATE TABLE Project.dbo.Table
(
id int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
col2 VARCHAR(50) NULL,
...
...
);
```

You can either add `PRIMARY KEY` with the column name like this `id int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,` or at the end after defining all columns like this `CONSTRAINT PK_Table PRIMARY KEY(id)`

SQL Server does not allow you to add `IDENTITY` by altering a table. use `GO` between `IF EXISTS ...DROP TABLE` and the `CREATE TABLE` statements to run those statements in separate batches.

Answer (score 9):

My preferred method for a *non-empty table* is to use the `ALTER TABLE ... SWITCH` method which is a meta-data-only operation.

This is a simple test-bed setup, consisting of the initial table, named `dbo.SwitchTest1`, and the target table containing an `IDENTITY`, named `dbo.SwitchTest2`:

```
USE tempdb;
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.SwitchTest1') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE dbo.SwitchTest1;
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.SwitchTest2') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE dbo.SwitchTest2;
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.SwitchTest1
(
    ID INT NOT NULL 
        CONSTRAINT PK_SwitchTest1
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    , SomeVal VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE dbo.SwitchTest2
(
    ID INT NOT NULL 
        CONSTRAINT PK_SwitchTest2
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
        IDENTITY(1,1)
    , SomeVal VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO dbo.SwitchTest1(ID, SomeVal)
VALUES (1, 'This is a test');
```

Here, we use the `ALTER TABLE ... SWITCH` method to replace the data in `dbo.SwitchTest2` table with data from `dbo.SwitchTest1`, while maintaining the definition of `dbo.SwitchTest2` including the `IDENTITY` column.  Although not strictly necessary, you probably want to rename any constraints included in the definition of `dbo.SwitchTest2` after the fact to match what they used to be called in `dbo.SwitchTest1`.  I've done that below for the primary key.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
BEGIN TRY
    ALTER TABLE dbo.SwitchTest1 SWITCH TO dbo.SwitchTest2;
    DROP TABLE dbo.SwitchTest1;
    EXEC sp_rename @objname = 'dbo.SwitchTest2'
        ,@newname = 'SwitchTest1', @objtype = 'object';
    EXEC sp_rename @objname = 'PK_SwitchTest2'
        , @newname = 'PK_SwitchTest1', @objtype = 'object';
    EXEC sp_recompile @objname = 'dbo.SwitchTest1';
    DBCC CHECKIDENT('dbo.SwitchTest1');
    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END CATCH
```

In the code above, I've also added a call to `sp_recompile` - this causes stored procedures, triggers, and user-defined functions to be [recompiled the next time that they are run](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181647.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). It does this by dropping the existing plan from the procedure cache forcing a new plan to be created the next time that the procedure or trigger is run.  This is A Good Thing™ since the object_id for the table `dbo.SwitchTest1` table has changed.  Also, I'm running `DBCC CHECKIDENT('<tablename>');` to cause the `IDENTITY()` column to be updated with the next valid value to be used by an `INSERT` operation.

Here, we're inserting a value into the `SomeVal` column without specifying a value for the `ID` column, which is now an `IDENTITY` column:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.SwitchTest1 (SomeVal)
VALUES ('This is another test');
```

And the results:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.SwitchTest1;
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As you are on SQL Server 2012 you could also create a [sequence object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx) per table and apply it to the desired auto incrementing column with a default constraint that calls `next value for`.

The two methods have some differences in behaviour which you may or may not find desirable.

1. `identity` columns are not updatable.
2. Greater control over cache size with sequence
3. The sequence value can be acquired before the insert if needed but if using sequences the various `identity` related functions obviously won't work.
4. Inserts of large amounts of rows can be faster with `identity` due to fewer log buffer flushes.

Answer (score 1):

**Resolved!**

Just need to click on Properties inside the table, and in "Identity column: " insert the name of a column

Comment: be aware this actually drops and recreates the table.